# Deletion of many number of records using BULK COLLECT

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to delete many thousands of records using BULK COLLECT concept. The table's record uniqueness is defined by 4 columns viz., NUMBER_ID, JOB_VALUE, JOB_TYPE, JOB_DATE. I need to delete records based on these four columns. I wrote the following code. However it errors out saying 1. "V_JOB_VAL' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement" 2. cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor "L_JOB_RID". Could you please suggest where I am doing wrong?

```
** Edited Code **

ALTER TABLE JOB_SAMPLE NOLOGGING;

ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

DECLARE 

TYPE V_JOB_RID IS TABLE OF JOB_SAMPLE.JOB_ROW_ID%TYPE;
TYPE V_JOB_DT IS TABLE OF JOB_SAMPLE.JOB_DATE%TYPE;
TYPE V_JOB_TY IS TABLE OF JOB_SAMPLE.JOB_TYPE%TYPE;
TYPE V_JOB_VAL IS TABLE OF JOB_SAMPLE.JOB_VALUE%TYPE;

L_JOB_RID V_JOB_RID := V_JOB_RID();
L_JOB_DT V_JOB_DT := V_JOB_DT();
L_JOB_TY V_JOB_TY := V_JOB_TY();
L_JOB_VAL V_JOB_VAL := V_JOB_VAL();
L_DELETE_BUFFER PLS_INTEGER := 50000;

CURSOR CDELETE IS

SELECT  /*+ PARALLEL(10) */ 
       T3.JOB_ROW_ID, 
       T3.JOB_DATE, 
       T3.JOB_TYPE, 
       T3.JOB_VALUE
FROM   JOB_T1 T1, 
       JOB_T2 T2, 
       JOB_SAMPLE T3
WHERE T1.ROW_ID = T2.JOB_T1_ID
AND   T3.JOB_ROW_ID = T1.JOB_ID
AND   T2.T2_VAL = T3.JOB_VALUE
AND   T1.NAME = T3.JOB_TYPE
AND   TO_DATE(T2.T2_DT,'DD-MON-YY') = TO_DATE(T3.JOB_DATE,'DD-MON-YY');

BEGIN

OPEN CDELETE;
LOOP
FETCH CDELETE BULK COLLECT INTO L_JOB_RID, L_JOB_DT, L_JOB_TY, L_JOB_VAL LIMIT L_DELETE_BUFFER;
EXIT WHEN L_JOB_RID.COUNT < L_DELETE_BUFFER;
FORALL I IN 1..L_JOB_RID.COUNT

DELETE /*+ PARALLEL(10) */ JOB_SAMPLE 
WHERE  JOB_ROW_ID = L_JOB_RID(I)
AND    JOB_DATE = L_JOB_DT(I)
AND    JOB_TYPE = L_JOB_TY(I)
AND    JOB_VALUE = L_JOB_VAL(I);

COMMIT;

END LOOP;

CLOSE CDELETE;

COMMIT;

END;

ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL DML;
```

Please let me know.

Thank you !

Comment: 1)  V_JOB_VAL -> L_JOB_VAL

2)  `NOTFOUND` is cursor parameter. `CDELETE%NOTFOUND`. But better will be exit when last loop has fetched less than the limit.  EXIT WHEN L_JOB_RID.count < L_DELETE_BUFFER;

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz This worked perfectly ! 
One small question ! If possible, could you please let me know why are we using "EXIT WHEN L_JOB_RID.count < L_DELETE_BUFFER;" ? This improved the job performance significantly.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz The procedure is getting executed successfully however the records are not getting deleted. Is it because in the DELETE statement, JOB_ROW_ID, JOB_DATE, JOB_TYPE are JOB_VALUE  are comparing with numbers in the array instead of values. Could you please help me here on this?

Comment: Number in arrays ? do you mean array's index? or what

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz Array's Index. Because when I execute the job, nothing is getting deleted. Is there any workaround so that the delete works?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. update your question with current code

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz I updated the current code and executed it. But no records are getting deleted.

Comment: move `EXIT WHEN L_JOB_RID.COUNT < L_DELETE_BUFFER;` after delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

Start by changing

`FETCH CDELETE BULK COLLECT INTO L_JOB_RID, L_JOB_DT, L_JOB_TY, V_JOB_VAL`

into

`FETCH CDELETE BULK COLLECT INTO L_JOB_RID, L_JOB_DT, L_JOB_TY, L_JOB_VAL`